# Rails one to many confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to wrap my head around associations in Rails. I come from iOS development background. I have a basic one-to-many working I think but I feel like I'm doing it wrong, so I'm asking on here to make sure.

So far, I have

### user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cats
end
```

### cat.rb

```
class Cat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

I have generated my migration like so:

```
rails generate migration add_user_to_cats user:references
```

### Migration file

```
class AddUserToCats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :cats, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

### Route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cats
  resources :users
  get '/users/:id/cats', to: 'users#user_cats'
  get '/adopt/:id', to: 'users#adopt'
end
```

When user go to `localhost:3000/users/1/cats` for example, it executes my controller method:

```
def user_cats
  cats = Cat.where(user_id: params[:id])
  render json: cats
end
```

### Question

First of all, is this the correct way to fetch all cats for a user ?

It just doesn't feel right...

Coming from an iOS development background and using CoreData, I am used to being able to do something like:

```
cats = user.cats
```

and

```
user = cat.owner
```

but my initial encounter with Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecords doesn't seem to suggest so.

Is it possible for Rails to do what is shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the one of many ways of fetching the associated records. You can also do

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@cats = @user.cats
```

***or***

You can also use `joins` or `includes`

```
@user_cats = User.joins(:cats)
```

***or***

```
@user_cats = User.includes(:cats)
```

Comment: Aye...what the heck...I tried that earlier it was telling me user does not have column "cats" (which is true because my sql users table does indeed not have "cats" column). Why is it working now....this is bizarre T_T

Comment: I tried to replicate it, couldn't anymore. I think I'm in the Matrix...anyone got a red pill?